# How do I repair "Author1, Author2, & Author3" citations with citet* in natbib?

Tags: natbib

This is possibly a very obscure problem. I tried searching for solutions but I had a hard time getting search engines to accept a literal ", &" string.

The problem is basically this. I'm using natbib with round and authoryear options. I'm using the citation style of *[Monthly Notices of the Royal Astronomical Society](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mnras)* (mn2e.bst), which says the first reference to a three-author paper must display all three names in full on the first citation and "et al." thereafter. So, if I make two citations to a paper by Smith, Jones and Parker, the first citation should be "Smith, Jones & Parker (2012)" and the second should be "Smith et al. (2012)".

This means the first citation should use the `citet`*. But then the output is

Smith, Jones, & Parker (2012)

which is just plain wrong. My sysadmins are allergic to updating (I'm on RHEL 5, writing this in FF3.6...) so I've got an old version of natbib. I tried playing with the punctuation with `\bibpunct` but I couldn't remove the correct comma. I realise this is basically the same as the standard formats (e.g. `plainnat`) writing "and" instead of "&" so I guess I'm asking how to remove that Oxford comma.

As required, here's a minimal example.

eg.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\begin{document}
\citet*{sjp12}
\bibliographystyle{mn2e}
\bibliography{eg}
\end{document}
```

eg.bib

```
@ARTICLE{sjp12,
   author = {{Smith}, A. and {Jones}, B. and {Parker}, C.},
    title = "{A paper title}",
  journal = {Journal of Amazing Science},
 keywords = {natbib},
     year = 2012,
    month = feb,
   volume = 314,
    pages = {159}
}
```

Comment: It is rather difficult to debug an old version which is not present on current system. I don't get the comma with a recent natbib and the mn2e.bst (version 1.1b) from CTAN. But as far as I can see it is not possible to insert such a comma through natbib. It is mn2e.bst which decide if it is present. So you should try to update the bst. (Regardless how allergic to updating your sysadmin is: you must have a local texmf tree where you can put newer versions of packages.)

Comment: D'oh! It's my fault. I'm using a [modified version of mn2e.bst](http://www.mpe.mpg.de/~williams/mn2ebst/) that eliminates the too-many-author problem. The standard version of mn2e.bst doesn't have this issue. I guess this can be closed as it doesn't really involve standard TeX packages.